# Como fazer uma div de altura igual ao da div contêiner? (conteiner maior que o viewport)

Tags: html, css

Sendo que não quero definir a altura da div contêiner, pois quero que ela aumente dinamicamente de acordo com o conteúdo?

```
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="esquerda">
   <!--Esta div não terá conteúdo e seguira a altura da div conteiner(maior que o viewport).-->
   </div>
 <div class="conteúdo">
 <p>Aqui vai o conteúdo. Esta div não terá altura fixa.</p>
 </div>
  <div class="direita">
   <!--Esta div não terá conteúdo e seguira a altura da div conteiner (maior que o viewport).-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A div mencionada não tem conteúdo interno. Só a div contêiner tem.

Comment: A div mencionada não tem conteúdo interno. Só a div contêiner tem

O que eu coloco na div conteúdo aumenta o tamanho da div contêiner, eu apenas gostaria que as div .esquerda e .direita acompanhassem isto. Todas as respostas que encontrei pesquisando falam sobre aumentar até 100% do viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione a seguinte propriedade a sua classe `.conteiner`:

```
.conteiner {position: relative}
```

Para as divs que vão expandir de acordo com o conteúdo (esquerda e direita):

```
.expandir {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    width:20px;
    background: yellow; 
}
.esquerda {left:0}
.direita {right:0}
```

E para centralizar a div `.conteudo`:

```
.conteudo {margin:0 20px}
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ecsn0xv/).

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui aqui usando a técnica css-table descrita nesse [link](http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-equal-height/). Já havia dado certo, mas estou usando o dreamweaver e por algum motivo ele não exibiu o resultado corretamente, eu havia olhado na guia design. Testei no navegador e está ok.